# Check for duplicates before array insertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, duplicates

```
keysArray: ['key1', 'key2', ..., 'keyn']
originalObject: key-value pairs { key1: value1, key2: value2, ..., keyn: valuen}
updatedObject: pairs with up to n updates values { key1: updatedValue1, key2: value2, key3: updateValue3, ..., keyn: valuen}
```

I want to pass ONLY updated elements of the `updatedObject` to `updateObjectFunction()`. However, I don't want to pass in elements where a key appears twice with different values.

So far, I have:

```js
for (key of keysArray) {
  if originalObject[key] !== updatedObject[key] {
    updatedElements[key] = updatedObject[key];
  }
}
updateObjectFunction(updatedElements);
```

How can I avoid pushing duplicated elements into `updatedElements` effectively? or if I should redesign the process to be more efficient. I want to use only native JavaScript functions. I considered using `some()` to filter out duplicated elements within the for loop, but I think that would be too slow.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: What is `updatedElements`?  An array or an object.  It looks like you may be using it like an object.  If so, keys cannot be duplicated in an object.

Comment: You may want to look into using Sets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set. By default, they only allow unique items. Don't know if this would match your usage scenario.

Comment: @Taplar It's an object. You're right. Keys can't be duplicated so there is no use for duplicate removals.

Comment: where do you *push* something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicate keys:

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

```js
// "one" is in the list twice:
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'five']

console.log([...new Set(arr)])
```